# SQL Alchemy Inconsistant Error On Program Close

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a script that does a lot of work with SQL however to avoid potentially damaging SQL queries also has a lot of conditions were it uses exit(). When exiting with a connection open sometimes there is no problem, however sometimes it throws a large error (posted below). There is no functional difference in the script, I just don't want someone using the code other than me seeing a large error that only occasionally happens.

Here is the minimum reproducible example.

```
import mysql as db

#set up connection to mysql
engine = db.create_engine(CORRECT CONNECTION INFO)
con = engine.connect()
exit()
```

Here is the error.

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ConnectionRecord.checkout.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x2b384c2a71e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 
529, in <lambda>
  File "/python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 
696, in _finalize_fairy
  File "/python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1307, in 
error
  File "/python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1519, in 
isEnabledFor
TypeError: unorderable types: int() >= NoneType()
```

This problem also occurs with quit(), but doesn't occur if the script reaches the end of the code and closes itself. It only occurs when I end it early and only about 1 in 3 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that if you close the connection before exiting this error never occurs. I assume that the connection is automatically closed by sqlalchemy if the script finishes.

Solution.

```
import mysql as db

#set up connection to mysql
engine = db.create_engine(CORRECT CONNECTION INFO)
con = engine.connect()
con.close()
exit()
```

The error never occurs in this case.